# numpy TypeError: ufunc 'invert' not supported for the input types, and the inputs

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, machine-learning, logistic-regression

For the code below:

```
def makePrediction(mytheta, myx):
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------
    pr = sigmoid(np.dot(myx, mytheta))

    pr[pr < 0.5] =0
    pr[pr >= 0.5] = 1

    return pr

    # -----------------------------------------------------------------

# Compute the percentage of samples I got correct:
pos_correct = float(np.sum(makePrediction(theta,pos)))
neg_correct = float(np.sum(np.invert(makePrediction(theta,neg))))
tot = len(pos)+len(neg)
prcnt_correct = float(pos_correct+neg_correct)/tot
print("Fraction of training samples correctly predicted: %f." % prcnt_correct)
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-f0c91286cd02> in <module>()
     13 # Compute the percentage of samples I got correct:
     14 pos_correct = float(np.sum(makePrediction(theta,pos)))
---> 15 neg_correct = float(np.sum(np.invert(makePrediction(theta,neg))))
     16 tot = len(pos)+len(neg)
     17 prcnt_correct = float(pos_correct+neg_correct)/tot

TypeError: ufunc 'invert' not supported for the input types, and the inputs
```

Why is it happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.invert.html):

> Parameters:
>         x : array_like.
>             Only integer and boolean types are handled."

Your original array is floating point type (the return value of `sigmoid()`); setting values in it to 0 and 1 won't change the type. You need to use `astype(np.int)`:

```
neg_correct = float(np.sum(np.invert(makePrediction(theta,neg).astype(np.int))))
```

should do it (untested).

---

Doing that, the `float()` cast you have also makes more sense. Though I would just remove the cast, and rely on Python doing the right thing. 
In case you are still using Python 2 (but please use Python 3), just add

```
from __future__ import division
```

to let Python do the right thing (it won't hurt if you do it in Python 3; it just doesn't do anything). With that (or in Python 3 anyway), you can remove numerous other `float()` casts you have elsewhere in your code, improving readability.

Answer (score 7):

np.invert requires ints or bools, use the method [np.linalg.inv](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.inv.html) instead.